# Error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'std::vector<double>')

Tags: c++

this is my first StackOverflow.

When I run my code I get this error:

```
error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka 
std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'std::vector<double>')
```

The error is in line 9 but I don't know why.

This is my code:

```
1 #include <vector>
2 #include <iostream>
3 using namespace std;
4
5 int main() {
6
7    vector<double> numbers[10];
8    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
9        cin >> numbers[i];
10    }
11 }
```

This numbers are for the lines, they are not actually in the code.

Basically, what I want to create is program that will ask me for 10 numbers.

Oh, I nearly forgot! I use Code::Blocks, version 17.12.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Change `vector<double> numbers[10];` to `vector<double> numbers(10);`.

Comment: `vector<double> numbers[10]` created an array of 10 empty vectors of numbers, not a vector of 10 numbers.

Comment: Thank you @songyuanyao for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already gotten an answer to the question you asked, but I'd suggest going a step further: eliminate the `for` loop and don't bother specifying the size of the vector either:

```
vector<double> numbers;

copy_n(istream_iterator<double>(cin), 10, back_inserter(numbers));
```

Oh, and one other detail--you probably want to break (or never form) the habit of `using namespace std;`--it can lead to problems.

Comment: I'm using namespace std because I'm begginer. When I will get to know coding in c++ better, I will stop using it. Still, thanks for the help.